# twitter-bootstrap max width of input field

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I got a following set up using the lastest twitter bootstrap framework:

http://jsfiddle.net/hfexR/2/

I now want that the input field takes the maximum width when there is no button next to.

How can I do this with pure css or with twitter-bootstrap itself?

Something like inline-block should go, I just don't get it at the moment...

Comment: You shouldn't combine `.span4` and `.well`. Have you tried using a `.row-fluid` and spans inside the well ?

Comment: 1. Whats wrong combining span and wells 2. could you give me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : since bootstrap v3, classes have evolved so use col-xx-X classes to obtain the result explained below (further changes may be necessary)

---

[Live demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/hfexR/3/)

You could use a `.row-fluid` and use `.spanX` to make the inputs fill their container :

```html
<form class="form-search">
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query span12">
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-search">
  <div class="row-fluid">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query span8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn span4">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

It appears that a little fix is needed for the button/input combination :

```css
/* May not be the best way, not sure if BS has a better solution */
/* Fix for combining input and button spans in a row */
.row-fluid > input + button[class*="span"] {
    float: none;           /* Remove the */
    display: inline-block; /* floating   */
    margin-left: 0;        /* Stick it to the left */
}
```

Last thing, you shouldn't combine `.spanX` and `.well` because of the `padding` and borders and other things, here is [an example of why (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/6CVns/embedded/result/).

Comment: The span classes have been removed in bootstrap 3.

Comment: @krock indeed classes have changed but the spirit of the answer is the same, see col-xx-X classes and associates

Answer (score 2):

You can use te class input-block-level like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JMKuK/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span4 well">
    <form class="form-search">
      <input type="text" class="input-block-level search-query">
    </form>
    <form class="form-search">
      <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, input-block-level does the trick and is properly responsive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232627/perfect-100-width-of-parent-container-for-a-bootstrap-input