# Bootstrap full-width text-input within inline-form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling to create a textbox that fits the entire width of my *container* area.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form class="form-inline" role="form">           
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="search-church" placeholder="Your location (City, State, ZIP)">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Search</button>            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I do the above, the two form elements are in-line, as I expect, but don't take up more than a few columns, at best. Hovering over the `col-md-12` div in firebug shows it taking up the expected full width. It's just the text input that doesn't seem to fill. I even tried adding an in-line width value but it didn't change anything. I know this should be simple, just feeling really dumb now.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/4119/embedded/result/

**EDIT:**

The selected answer is thorough in every way and a wonderful help. It's what I ended up using. *However* I think my initial issue was actually a problem with the default MVC5 template within Visual Studio 2013. It contained this in Site.css:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Obviously that was blocking the text-input from expanding appropriately... Fair warning to future ASP.NET template users...

Comment: I just want to second your finding about the problem with the default MVC5 template. I just spend an hour researching this issue and (falsely) cursing at Bootstrap before I found a working sample in jsfiddle that prompted me to start again with a clean HTML page, and it worked fine. Only then did I figure there was an issue with the VS2013 template and came across this post.
Goodness knows why the decision for the max-width, but it goes to show you have to be careful when using other people's code. It's also testament to going back to basics when stuck with an issue like this.

Comment: Thanks, also using asp.net template, but I already set max-width of input to none, but it still doesn't take the whole width, only if I set it to 100% manually. But then the button right to it goes down, and I want it to stay in the same line.

Comment: @Killnine The edit in your question solved my headaches. It was in fact the problem, thank you for editing your post !

Comment: I removed that bit of CSS from my site.css file and i am still having the same issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: ughhhhh I've spent too much time for what ended up being the default css in site.css.

Comment: Godamn, I've been trying to figure out what was wrong with this bootstrap for days... Damn Asp.net template... I could kiss you for figuring that out. EDIT: For those that remove those lines, just change it to 100% instead.

Comment: It was the boilerplate ASP.NET MVC template site.css for me too!

Comment: Dayuuumn! Been struggling with this and turns out it's an MVC issue! How stupid I am for not inspecting the css properties of the textbox! Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: This was gold. Was struggling to find out what was going wrong

Comment: Thanks for this. Like many before me it seems., I spent a good hour or two trying to figure this out. (Don't forget to <Ctrl>F5 to totally refresh after editing site.css - that cost me a few minutes too :-))

Answer (score 113, accepted):

The bootstrap docs [says about this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline):

> Requires custom widths Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by
>   default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a
>   width on the form controls used within.

The default width of 100% as all form elements gets when they got the class `form-control` didn't apply if you use the `form-inline` class on your form.

You could take a look at the bootstrap.css (or .less, whatever you prefer) where you will find this part:

```
.form-inline {

  // Kick in the inline
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    // Inline-block all the things for "inline"
    .form-group {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    // In navbar-form, allow folks to *not* use `.form-group`
    .form-control {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto; // Prevent labels from stacking above inputs in `.form-group`
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    // Input groups need that 100% width though
    .input-group > .form-control {
      width: 100%;
    }

    [...]
  }
}
```

Maybe you should take a look at [input-groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups), since I guess they have exactly the markup you want to use (working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x8eqn/633)):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="search-church" placeholder="Your location (City, State, ZIP)">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See my edit above. I think the Site.css in the ASP.NET template may have gotten me on this one. However, this is a terrific answer and very helpful for future reference.

Comment: input groups are the way to go on this. Personally, I adjust the input group style to resemble an inline form when I don't want the button immediately beside the input. Working demo with Bootstrap LESS included: http://jsfiddle.net/silb3r/gwxc5c75/

Comment: nice! I know the question is bootstrap-specific, but if anyone else wants to drop it into a bootstrapless (not bootstrap LESS;) site I've extracted the relevant styles here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27413796/1241736

Comment: The Bootstrap link in the Fiddle is broken. It's probably pointing to a new version of Bootstrap and the Fiddle is no longer working.

Comment: @Chloe You're right, the fiddle was using a bootstrap css file that no longer exists. I just updated the fiddle, it's working again.

Comment: Just to save someone all of two seconds Googling, updated input groups link - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/input-group/

Answer (score 38):

have a look at something like this:

```
<form role="form">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
          </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
      </div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n6c7v/1/

Comment: Your answer helped me realise I was simply missing `class="form-control"` in the input fields.

Answer (score 11):

As stated in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232627/perfect-100-width-of-parent-container-for-a-bootstrap-input/33142412#33142412), try removing instances of the `input-group` class and see if that helps.

refering to bootstrap:

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling.
>   All textual , , and  elements with
>   .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default. Wrap labels and
>   controls in .form-group for optimum spacing.

Comment: Per morten this doesn't apply to inline forms. Thus, you need the input-group to force it to be 100%

Answer (score 4):

> Try something like below to achieve your desired result

```
input {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flex-fill` class for `input`

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">           
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg flex-fill" id="search-church" placeholder="Your location (City, State, ZIP)">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg">Search</button>            
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap >4.1 it's just a case of using the flexbox utility classes. Just have a flexbox container inside your column, and then give all the elements within it the "flex-fill" class. As with inline forms you'll need to set the margins/padding on the elements yourself.

```css
.prop-label {
    margin: .25rem 0 !important;
}

.prop-field {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
  <div class="d-flex">
   <label class="flex-fill prop-label">Label:</label>
   <input type="text" class="flex-fill form-control prop-field">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is pretty old, but I stumbled upon it recently, found a solution that I liked better, and figured I'd share it.

Now that Bootstrap 5 is available, there's a new approach that works similarly to using `input-group`s, but looks more like an ordinary form, without any CSS tweaks:

```
<div class="row g-3 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <label>Label:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <input class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `col-auto` class makes those columns fit themselves to their contents (the label and the button in this case), and anything with a `col` class should be evenly distributed to take up the remaining space.